# Having trouble with exempt url

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to exempt a url in my project so that the user can bypass the middleware and reset their password without being logged in. However the urls I have placed in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS don't seem to fix this, instead the link to reset-password redirects the user to account/login.

settings.py:

```
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = {

r'^account/logout/$',
r'^account/register/$',
r'^account/reset-password$',
r'^account/reset-password/done/$',
r'^account/reset-password/confirm(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/$',
r'^account/reset-password/complete/$',

}
```

middleware.py:

```
url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path)for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

    if path == reverse('accounts:logout').lstrip('/'):
        logout(request)

    if request.user.is_authenticated and url_is_exempt:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

    elif request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
        return None

    else:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home),
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),

url(r'^reset-password/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password.html',
                              success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')), name='reset_password'),

url(r'^reset-password/done/$', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset-password/confirm(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/$',
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

main/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),


]
```

html: This is in {% else %} (user.is.authenticated)

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class="nav-link" href='{% url 'accounts:reset_password' %}'>Forgotten Password?</a>
```

Everything in html is properly formatted but I think some of the code is bugging out. Sorry about that

FYI: Register in exempt works!

So whats the problem? thnx

Comment: which version of django? and please share urls.py

Comment: urls.py has been added sorry I did add it guess I refreshed page. it is Django 2+ latest version.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're expecting this to work. Those are URL patterns, not actual URLs, so will never be equal to the current URL.

Comment: Try adding compiled version of urls.py. I haven't yet used middleware for login, and prefers mixins, have a go through this link `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbAzWll4UIA`

Comment: hahahaha I learned from that guy that's the project im doing right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exempt regex `r'^account/reset-password$'` does not have a trailing slash. This is inconsistent with the regex in your URL pattern, `r'^reset-password/$'`, which does have a trailing slash.